# data flow from multiple source to single destinantion in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I need to import the data from the multiple distributed database ( around 70 ) to the single source table .So how is it possible through SSIS 2008

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can run the same query against each of the 70 source servers, you can use a ForEach Loop with a single Data Flow Task. The source connection manager's `ConnectionString` should be an expression using the loop variables.

Here's an example reading the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view from multiple DBs. I created the following tables on my local instance:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
CREATE TABLE [MultiDbDemo].[SourceConnections](
    [DatabaseKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ServerName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SourceConnections] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DatabaseKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [MultiDbDemo].[SourceColumns](
    [ColumnKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ServerName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SchemaName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TableName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ColumnName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SourceColumns] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ColumnKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

This is the control flow for the SSIS package:
[image]

The Source_AdoDotNet connection manager's `ConnectionString` property is set to the following expression:
[image]

SQL_GetSourceList's `SQLStatement` property is `SELECT ServerName, DatabaseName FROM MultiDbDemo.SourceConnections`, and the `ResultSet` is mapped to the `User::SourceList` variable.

The ForEach Loop task is configured thusly:
[image]
Note that the ADO object source variable is set to the `User::SourceList` variable populated in the SQL_GetSourceList task.
[image]

And the data flow looks like this:
[image]

ADO_SRC_SourceInfo is configured thusly:
[image]

The next effect of all this is that, for each database listed in the SourceConnections table, we execute the query `SELECT LEFT(TABLE_SCHEMA, 50) AS SchemaName, LEFT(TABLE_NAME, 50) AS TableName, LEFT(COLUMN_NAME, 50) AS ColumnName FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and save the results in the SourceColumns table.

Answer (score 0):

You will still need 70 destination components. Simply specify the same table in all of them.